# Could you more explain about the compliance time specifies in the following sentence?

Tags: airworthiness-directive

For example Prior to accumulating 5,000 landings or within the next 1,000 landings after the effective date of this AD, whichever occurs later.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'a real-time'. There's no time limit in the wording you've posted, just limits on the number of landings.

Comment: Within the next [25 hours] time-in-service (TIS) after the effective date of this AD,
unless already done within the last [75 hours] TIS, and thereafter at intervals not to
exceed [100 hours] TIS from the last inspection, inspect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a threshold and phase-in.  The 5000 landings is the threshold and is landings since new, with a 1000 landing phase-in.

The phase-in is to accommodate airplanes close to, or over, the threshold; otherwise, everybody over the threshold would be grounded immediately, and someone close to the threshold would have only the hours remaining to the threshold to comply.

The effect is, if you have 4000 landings or less on the a/c, you have until 5000 landings since new.  If you have more than 4000 landings, you get 1000 landings from the release date of the AD to comply.

So if you are at 4100 landings, you get to 5100, 4500 landings, you get to 5500.  If you are at 6000 landings, you get to 7000.  And so on.

Just about any AD that doesn't have a hard calendar compliance date, like the one grounding the Max, will have this threshold and phase-in that is negotiated between the OEM and regulator based on risk and probability analysis that establishes how long a problem can be dormant without impacting fleet safety.

Comment: I understand thank you so much, but unclearly yet, different between whichever occurs later with whichever occurs first

Comment: It's whichever occurs later.  If your airplane has 4950 landings when the AD is issued, you've got 50 landings until you reach 5000.  So 1000 landings landings would occur later and you would have until then to comply.  If you have 1500 landings, you would have 3500 to reach 5000 so that would occur later than 1000 after issue.

Comment: All that matters is the "later" part. Think of it this way.  Everybody gets AT LEAST the phase-in period of 1000 landings to comply, but you don't want to penalize someone with a nearly new airplane with a 1000 landing compliance.   So you put in a 5000 landing threshold, so the phase-in, effectively, only applies to airplanes over 4000 landings so they get at least 1000 landings grace period.   People get confused because they see threshold and phase-in and have to realize that the phase-in applies to anybody within the phase-in period short of the threshold, as well as beyond the threshold.

Comment: Within the next [25 hours] time-in-service (TIS) after the effective date of this AD, unless already done within the last [75 hours] TIS, and thereafter at intervals not to exceed [100 hours] TIS from the last inspection, inspect... first is the 25 hours threshold? second, if the inspection already is done by the operator means that we only need an inspection at the interval and initial inspection is omitted for this situation

Answer (score 1):

You need to comply with the AD prior to accumulating 5,000 landings or within the next 1,000 landings after the effective date of the AD, whichever occurs later.

This is a very simple order compared to a few others.

Comment: actually, my question related to whichever occurs later, could you more explanation about that with example

Comment: Within the next [25 hours] time-in-service (TIS) after the effective date of this AD, unless already done within the last [75 hours] TIS, and thereafter at intervals not to exceed [100 hours] TIS from the last inspection, inspect... at first is the 25 hours threshold? second, if the inspection already is done by the operator means that we only need an inspection at the interval and initial inspection is omitted for this situation